# Modify and add of unlimited collection field

Tags: entities

I have a content who contains an unlimited collection field. Via a custom module, how can I get and set the informations which are in field collection in the content (nid) ?

I have read the api documentation of field collection but I don't understand how it works (I'm french..)
By example I see this function : field_collection_item_load, the parameter is an item but...what is an item ? xD

Another question, my field collection contains an another field collection. Is there a particular way to get and set this "sub"-field collection ?

If you can me a very sample example of get and set, I thank you very much

Comment: To save I have recently used this solution 14 here [Creating field collections](https://www.drupal.org/node/1106182#comment-7469570) to create field collections. To load and update them this should help if you haven't seen it already [Programmatically create and update field collection with Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1842304)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we are in a `hook_node_view()`, a `hook_preprocess_node()` or something and we have access to $node, and my collection field is 'field_collection_field':

```
<?php
if (!empty($node->field_collection_field)) {
  $collection_fields = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_collection_field');

  // Extract the field collection item ids
  $ids = array();

  foreach ($collection_field as $fc_field) {
      $ids[] = $fc_field['value'];
  }

  //Get the entities
  $collections = field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids);
  // dpm($collections); Devel output the items
  //Loop over the array - if you have more than one entity
  foreach($collections as $collection) {
    //Iterate over all member vars of the FieldCollectionItemEntity object
    foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
     // DO STUFF WITH COLLECTION FIELDS VALUES
    }
   }
 }//end if
```